# How can I find matches between two strings of the same text in different dataframes, with some differences between them?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have two dataframes, each with a column with a part of the same text.

Dataframe `A` has all the "sentences" of the text, while dataframe `B` has parts of these sentences, which can be part of one or more sentences and with some repetitions.

Example:

**A**

| index | sentence |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 'I was in the river.' |
| 1 | 'How was the water?' |
| 2 | 'Good, but cold' |

**B**

| index | sentence |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 'was in the river.' |
| 1 | 'was the water? Good' |
| 2 | 'Good, but co' |
| 3 | 'Good, but cold' |

Now I need to find the matches between the two dataframes.
Example:

| idx_B | idx_A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | [1,2] |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

I've tried to find the correspondences using `split`, `in`, `compare`, even with Levenshtein distance, but because of the size of the dataframe sometimes the sentences doesn't match, even knowing that `B` will always be a part of `A` in some way, since `A` has the complete text, and `B` parts of it.

Comment: Does `B` contain continuous parts of the whole text, or can there be 2 or more non-adjacent parts in one cell joined together? What do you mean by _repetitions_?

Comment: "*B will always be a part of A in some way, since A has the complete text, and B parts of it.*" from your example this is not fully true, `'was the water? Good'` and `'Good, but cold'` intersect but none of the string is a full substring of the other.

Comment: @Vitalizzare Dataframe A contains all the text, split in sentences. Dataframe B contains parts of this text, always a continuous part and sometimes repetitions can happen, like two rows with the same string. Unfortunately, these repetitions are important and can't be removed.

Comment: @mozway Sorry, I didn't explain that part well. Dataframe A contains all the text, split in sentences. Dataframe B contains parts of this text. I meant that because A contains all the text and B is an always continuous split, the words in B will occur in A, even if on split lines. As in index 1 of B which contains part of sentences 1 and 2 of A

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is not straightforward and the expected logic is not fully clear.

Assuming you consider a match whenever there are at least 2 partial words or at least 4 characters in common, you could use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) to identify the common substrings. You need to loop over all combinations of A and B with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

tmp = {}
for idxA, idxB in product(A.index, B.index):
    # get each sentence from their indices
    sA = A.loc[idxA, 'sentence']
    sB = B.loc[idxB, 'sentence']

    # find longest match
    m = SequenceMatcher(None, sA, sB).find_longest_match()
    common = sA[m[0]:m[2]+m[0]]
    common_strip = common.strip()

    # uncomment the line below to see the longest common string
    #print(f'"{sA}" / "{sB}":  "{common}"')
    # if a match (2 words, or at least 4 characters)
    # keep the pair of indices
    if ' ' in common_strip or len(common_strip)>=4:
        tmp.setdefault(idxB, []).append(idxA)

out = pd.DataFrame({'idx_B': tmp.keys(), 'idx_A': tmp.values()})
```

*Now you can use this logic to define custom rules to decide whether of not the common substring is a match.*

output:

```
   idx_B   idx_A
0      0     [0]
1      1  [1, 2]
2      2     [2]
3      3     [2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked perfectly, as you said I had to make some adjustments to suit my needs.
Saved my life! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create two dataframes
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['I was in the river.', 'How was the water? ', 'Good, but cold']})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['was in the river.', 'was the water? Good', 'Good, but co','Good, but cold']})

# Iterate over each row in df1
for index, row in dfB.iterrows():
# Check if the string in col1 of df1 exists in col1 of df2
 if row['sentence'] in ''.join(dfA['sentence']):
     print(row['sentence'], 'exists in df2')
```

Hope the above code resolves your problem. You can format the output the way you want.

If you have any queries let me know

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I had tried that way but because some sentences were split I ended up with wrong outputs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).